# Question regarding the intuition behind wave equation

Tags: waves, wavefunction, oscillators

The wave equation is given by

$\dfrac{δ²u}{δt²}$=v²$\dfrac{δ²u}{δx²}$

I am not interested in the derivation ,I am more **interested in the physical meaning** behind this equation ,

Why should the ***second derivative*** of the displacement of the particle with respect to ***time*** be equal to some constant times the ***second derivative*** of the displacement of the particle with respect to ***position***.

Comment: From $x = vt$ we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial (\frac{x}{v})} = v \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. So solutions of $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t,x)= v \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x)$ will have $x$ and $t$ related by $x = vt$, i.e. be functions $f(x - vt)$, positively traveling waves. But what about $x = - vt$? We now have $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} = - v \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, i.e. negatively travelling waves $f(x + vt)$. What equation would naturally descibe situations with positively and negatively traveling waves simultaneously? You guessed it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/244130/83835).

Comment: @march ,your answer was good ; but I have a question the curvature is given by ,$\dfrac{dT}{ds}$ ,,where $T$ is the unit $Tangent$ vector ,but the curvature according to you is $\dfrac{d²u}{dx²}$,I don't get it .

Comment: I was using curvature in the colloquial sense, not in the "differential geometry of curves" sense: I just meant that how the function is curved determines how much it pulls back.  The correct term to use there is the "concavity", which is exactly what I use later on.

Comment: Yeah ,sorry ,I realised that later

Comment: @march ,I get it now ,at the point where the acceleration is the most ,the concavity turns out to be maximum ,but could you account for the inclusion of $v²$ in the equation ?

Comment: Well, it needs to be there for the units to work out, and then you solve the equation and see that it happens to be the speed of the waves.  Frankly, I think the best intuition for the wave equation come from the derivation for it.  My explanation of how you take the difference between the derivatives on either side to get the net force is *part of the derivation*.  I've just extracted that bit to explain the spatial derivatives. A heuristic explanation will *never* explain all the constants in an equation; that requires the derivation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ,explaining the relation between the second derivatives .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The physical meaning of different terms in wave equations depends on the context, we are studying. Supposing this to mechanics. It's easy to see that the term
$$\partial^2_t\psi(x,t)$$
is the acceleration of the particle. Here $\psi$ is the displacement of the particle. Furthermore, consider the system to be the chain of particles connected with spring. The acceleration now comes from spring force which in term depends on relative displacement from the mean.

Since a particle is connected to two-particle, one on the left and the other on the right, we have two differences (single derivative) from the mean which in turn take the form of a double derivative.
$$(\Delta \psi)_\text{left}-(\Delta \psi)_\text{right}=\Delta^2\psi$$

That's the reason why there's a double derivative with respect to space coordinate.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\nabla^2 \psi$? *"which in turn take the form of a double derivative"*

Comment: I am referring to a single dimension